# How to find a polygon error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, multipart, validation

I loaded the following multipart polygon in QGIS which consists of three separate polygons. The highlighted (yellow) polygon consists of the bigger upper part and the smaller lower part.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

My aim is to render the same multipart polygon in an Android app. Therefore, I extract the points of each polygon. Then I render the coordinates (latitude, longitude) in the app.

However, the Android rendering shows up with an error as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Android screenshot]

It looks like there is a **false connection** between two points. I cannot see this line in QGIS - neither in the polygon nor in the points layer.

Is there any way I can detect this error in QGIS and fix it?